# Handle Scanner exception on Java program

Tags: java, exception, java.util.scanner

I am working on a school project. I have all the functionality working but when I submit the project through Mimir, during deposits and withdraws it gives the following error:

```
Enter the amount you want to Deposit :$Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException

13 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
14 at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
15 at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2345)
16 at BankAccount.deposit(BankAccount.java:24)
17 at SavingsAccountDemo.main(SavingsAccountDemo.java:30)
```

The project does says the following: Please make sure that your classes throw appropriate exceptions when an attempt is made to insert invalid data.

I tried to add the try and catch with `java.util.InputMismatchException e` but it doesn't seem to be fixing it. I think it's because the userInput is a double and they are entering something different. Any ideas how can I fix that? Here is the code:

```
///SavingsAccountDemo class
import java.util.*;
public class SavingsAccountDemo {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        double startingBalance;
        double interestRate;
        String userInput;
                
        System.out.print("Enter beginning balance :$");
        startingBalance = keyboard.nextDouble();
        
        System.out.print("Enter interest rate(whole number) :%");
        interestRate = keyboard.nextDouble();
        
        double bal = startingBalance;
        double rate = interestRate;
        
        BankAccount ba = new BankAccount(startingBalance, interestRate);
        BankDemo sv = new BankDemo(bal, rate);
        
        while(startingBalance > -1) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Enter D for deposit" + "\nEnter W to Withdraw" + "\nEnter B for Balance" + 
                                    "\nEnter M for Monthly Process" + "\nEnter E to Exit");
                userInput = keyboard.next().toLowerCase();
                
                if("d".equals(userInput)) {
                    ba.deposit();
                } else if("w".equals(userInput)) {
                    ba.withdraw();
                } else if("b".equals(userInput)) {
                    ba.totalBalance();
                } else if("m".equals(userInput)) {
                    ba.monthlyProcess();
                } else if("e".equals(userInput)) {
                    ba.exit();
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    System.out.print("Error, option not valid\n");
                }
            }
            catch (java.util.InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.print("Error");
            }
        }
    }

}
///BankAccount class
import java.util.*;
public class BankAccount {
    protected double balance;
    protected double numDeposits;
    protected double numWithdrawals;
    protected double annualRate;
    protected double monthlyServCharg;
    protected boolean active;
    
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    public BankAccount(double startingBalance, double interestRate) {
        balance = startingBalance;
        annualRate = interestRate /= 100.0;
        if(balance < 25) {
            active = false;
        } else
            active = true;
    }
    public void deposit() {
        try {
        double valueD;
        
        System.out.print("Enter the amount you want to Deposit :$");
        valueD = keyboard.nextDouble();
        if(valueD < 0) {
            System.out.println("Error: Must enter positive value\n");
        }
        if( balance + valueD >= 25 && !active) {
            System.out.print("Your account is now ACTIVE\n");
            active = true;      
        }
        balance += valueD;
        numDeposits++;
        } 
        catch (java.util.InputMismatchException e){
            keyboard.nextLine();
        }
    }
    public void withdraw() {
        try {
            double valueW;
            
            System.out.print("Enter the amount you want to withdraw :$");
            valueW = keyboard.nextDouble();
            if(valueW < 0) {
                System.out.println("Error: Must enter positive value\n");
            }
            balance -= valueW;
            numWithdrawals++;
            if(balance < 0) {
                System.out.print("ERROR: Transaction declined!! This transaction will cause overdraft or zero balance\n");
                balance += valueW;
            } else if(balance <= 25 && active) {
                System.out.print("Your balance is less than minimum balance. Your account is now INACTIVE\n");
                active = false;
                }
            if(numWithdrawals > 4) {
                balance --;
                System.out.print("You have exceeded monthly limit of withdrawals. Fee of $1 charged\n");
            }
        } 
        catch (java.util.InputMismatchException e) {
            keyboard.nextLine();
        }
        
    }
    public void totalBalance() {
        System.out.printf("Your Balance is: %.2f\n", balance);
    }
    public void calcInterest() {
        double monRate = annualRate / 12;
        double monInt = balance * monRate;
        balance += monInt;
    }
    public void monthlyProcess() {
        calcInterest();
        balance -= monthlyServCharg;
        numWithdrawals = 0;
        numDeposits = 0;
        monthlyServCharg = 0;
        System.out.printf("Your Balance after Monthly process is: %.2f\n", balance);
    }
    
    public void exit() {
        totalBalance();
        System.out.print("Thank you. Bye");
    }
}
```

Comment: The code you've posted doesn't match your exception, i.e. the code contains `nextDouble()` in `deposit()` but the exception mentions `nextFloat()`. That seems to indicate the code you've submitted is not your current version. Also not that albeit a `InputMismatchException` extends `NoSuchElementException` the catch-block will only catch that specific subclass and not any other `NoSuchElementException`. You're getting the base exception here so of course it won't be caught.

Comment: @Thomas I adjusted to the `nextDouble()` which is the latest code I sent, still shows the same error just replace that. I have been on this for good 4 hours, any ideas how can I fix it?

Comment: If you want to catch the exception do a `catch(NoSuchElementException)`. If you want to fix the error in the first place we might need some more info e.g. what the input was.